# c++ Temporary object question

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

Is there a difference in the number of temp objects created between these 2 functions?

```
string foo1() {
    return "";
} 

string foo2() {
    string s = "";
    return s;
}
```

This is a homework question so please assume there is no compiler optimization.

Comment: Since this is a homework question, shouldn't you resolve this on your own?

Comment: Instead of using `string`, you could try it with a class of your own, which would inform you every time one got created or destroyed.

Comment: @Beta: That would not tell you if the object was *temporary* or not.

Comment: @DeadMG: Isn't a temporary object just an unnamed object on the stack? If you know what objects are being created, and you can see which ones have names, can't you just subtract?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No- only one *temporary* is created. The object on the stack of the function is not a temporary, it is an lvalue. The string literal is also an lvalue. Both involve exactly the same process- returning a string constructed from an lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Without any optimization, namely, NRVO (named return-value optimization), the second code will produce 2 temporaries while the first will produce one.

Comment: Something with a name is not a temporary. And the code without NRVO may produce 2 temporaries, but it may also only produce one.

Comment: @Xeo The compiler does not have to create a temporary for the constructor call, and probably won't.

Comment: @Neil: The 3 was a typo while editing. Also, why may code without NRVO only produce 1 copy?

Comment: Isn't return-value optimization non-standard in C++03?

Comment: @Xeo The temporary that is returned. The constructor call has nothing to do with NVRO.

Comment: @Neil: Meh, that was me misinterpreting my own testing code, which was wondering me anyways.

Comment: there's nothing non-standard about RVO: if the compiled code has the exact same result, any optimization is permitted. Things like constructors with side-effects make RVO hard/impossible to do, and probably a compiler won't in that case.

Comment: @rubenvb: You're wrong. It's perfectly Standard-legal to elide copy (and move) construction, *even if* the copy constructor has side effects. This is explicitly stated in the Standard.

Comment: @Andre No, it isn't.  The compiler is more or less free to make as many or as few copies as it likes.

Comment: @DeadMG: So if there's a constructor that increments a global `int`, and it's elided, optimization can change the behavior of the program and all this is Standard-conformant? If so, ok, didn't know that, and it is surprising...

Comment: @rubenv Yes, that's the case - you shouldn't do anything in a copy constructor except copying.

Comment: @rubenvb: As @Neil says, that is totally compliant. Normally, the compiler can only change the behaviour with zero observable side-effects, but this case is special. I don't know of any other special cases. Infact, it's common to use a copy constructor that outputs to `cout` to show whether or not it was elided.

Comment: @Neil, DeadMG: Thanks, something to keep in mind. Any strong reasoning behind this behavior?

Comment: @rubenvb: Before move semantics, then copy elision was the only way of automatically removing needless and expensive copies. Much performance has been saved, and even observer-dependent classes like `shared_ptr` don't have their necessary semantics violated. It doesn't really break any code that we would actually *want* to write and provides significant optimization.,

Answer (score -2):

No difference. In both cases a new string object is created (1 - implicitly, 2 - explicitly).

---

Both examples do the following:
1. Push pointer of the empty string to the stack (or write it to the register).
2. Create new instance of string class (with specified string).
3. Write pointer of newly created instance to EAX (as the result)

---

My apologies, this is C++ question whereas I thought about C# :)

That means the instance of string class will be duplicated (not returned by pointer). Anyway, both examples create only one instance of string class (1 - implicitly, 2 - explicitly), then all bytes of this instance (temporary object) will be pushed to the stack as the result.

**The answer**: no difference, only one temporary object (provided no compiler optimization applied).

NOTE: in both cases compiler allocates the same number of bytes in the stack to store the instance of string class, and the "" (empty string) is already loded to the memory (no allocation). The only difference is that 1st example creates an instance of string class implicitly.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Because the bytes will *not* be pushed, the copy constructor will be invoked. The difference is very significant.